# Trigger Jquery Event after an onsubmit

Tags: .net, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, forms, action

I would like to trigger a Div to open after a form completes an action.  But I need to it only happen based on one particular action so it is specific.  I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: Do you mean *after* the new page loads?

Comment: Well a new page will not load.  The page will refresh.  Basically.  Something is being added to a cart.  After it is added to the cart.  I want to to display a message.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so if a new page is not loaded after your form completes an action (i.e. you have submitted it), I would assume you mean you're not redirecting the user to a different page; you're just posting back the current "Cart" page with the updated data.

So your question is, "How do I display content on my page only following a postback".

While [jQuery does all things](http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif), it's probably not needed here (if I've interpreted your problem correctly, at least).

You just need to check whether the page is being loaded for the first time or is being loaded in response to a postback.  For that you use the `Page.IsPostBack` property:

```
<% if (Page.IsPostBack) { %>
   <div id="myMessage"><p>You added something to your cart.</p></div>
<% } %>
```

If this isn't what you meant, you need to explain your question a bit more.

Comment: Sounds a little bit closer to what I need.  However.  The message will only pop when a specific item is added.  And the item that is being added is being executed from the action.  And from what I've read IsPostBack is gone in MVC?

Comment: Ok, it might help if you post some of your code.  And I haven't seen anywhere that the IsPostBack property is being deprecated?