# How to retrieve onSubmit event using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The problem is when i am using window.onbeforeunload. While i am clicking o submit button, then the pop up is shown.but i need only when backbutton or refresh is done.For this, I thought we get event right. so whenever unload is calling i just want to test whether the event is from onsubmit.if it is , we does not give popup. so for this i need to know how submit event is detected.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
    if ($('.formFields').find('tr.item').length || $('.formFields').find('tr.section').length) {
        var dis = discardWarning();
        return dis;
    } else {
        return;
    }

};

var discardWarning = function() {
    return "Your current work will be discarded.";
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trigger Jquery Event after an onsubmit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550541/trigger-jquery-event-after-an-onsubmit)

Comment: You want to this warning to user when user makes some changes and leaves this pages without saving them right?

Comment: yea exactly.@itzmukeshy7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a flag variable when the form is submitted and response is captured.

```
/* default */
window.leavingAfterSubmission = false;

$('#your-form').on('submit', function(e) {
  window.leavingAfterSubmission = true;
});
```

Then you can check for this flag on your `onbeforeunload` event handler.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  if ( !window.leavingAfterSubmission ) {
    // flag is false, meaning the user is leaving by refresh or back button
    return discardWarning();
  }

  // flag is true, meaning the user is leaving by form submission
  // empty return to prevent the dialog
  return;
};
```

Comment: can i have a example.. i mean just try to write it in my above code please.. I am unable to understand

Comment: I added the onbeforeunload handler code as well, check if it works this way please.

Comment: Can you clarify your question a little better please, I don't understand your scenario. What do  you mean by "disable the next page"

Comment: I mean when i am clicking on leave page , the page is redirected to previous page.. In the previous page , forward button of browser is enabled.. So i am able to click on --> button of browser and go to the page where we came out of it. So for that i want to disable the forward button of browser once leave page is clicked in popup